# kernel32.GetModuleHandleA returning strange value

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes

By running the code of python below with `python main.py wmi.dll`, I want to get the loading address of DLL. However, the value of `loadAddr` is `0`. What is wrong in the code?

```
from ctypes import *
import sys
import string

kernel32 = windll.kernel32
print(kernel32)

if len(sys.argv)!=2:
    print("Usage : dll.py<DLL to resolve>")
    sys.exit(0)
windll.LoadLibrary(sys.argv[1])
loadAddr = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(sys.argv[1])
print(str(loadAddr)+"\n")
print(sys.argv[1])
print(hex(loadAddr) + " Load Address")
print(hex(loadAddr + int("0x1000",16)) + " Text segment")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to define the `.argtypes` and `.restype` of the functions you are using with `ctypes`.  `GetModuleHandleA` takes a `LPCSTR` (equivalent to a `bytes` object in Python), and `GetModuleHandleW` takes a `LPCWSTR` (equivalent to a `str` object in Python).  Additionally, they both return `HDMODULE`, which is a 64-bit value of 64-bit systems, but the default `.restype` if unspecified is `c_int` (32-bit).

Here's correct code to call either version:

```py
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

k32 = ct.WinDLL('kernel32')
k32.GetModuleHandleA.argtypes = w.LPCSTR,
k32.GetModuleHandleA.restype = w.HMODULE
k32.GetModuleHandleW.argtypes = w.LPCWSTR,
k32.GetModuleHandleW.restype = w.HMODULE

wmi = ct.WinDLL('wmi')

print(k32.GetModuleHandleA(b'wmi'))  # byte string
print(k32.GetModuleHandleW('wmi'))   # Unicode string
print(k32.GetModuleHandleA('wmi'))   # calling with wrong type
```

Sample output below.  Note this value is larger than a 32-bit value could hold (>4294967295) and would be truncated and incorrect if `.restype` wasn't set, and the error message would not occur if `.argtypes` wasn't set.

```
1864530853888
1864530853888
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(k32.GetModuleHandleA('wmi'))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

There are some problems with your code:

1. The main one:

   - [[MS.Docs]: GetModuleHandleA function (libloaderapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlea) (or any *ANSI* function variant from *WinAPI*) takes a *8bit* string (***char****) as argument
   - In *Python **3*** (I assume that's what you are using) strings are *16bit* (***wchar_t****)

   To get past this you should use: *kernel32.GetModuleHandle**W***. Example:

   > ```py
   > >>> import ctypes as ct
   > >>> # kernel32 is alsready loaded
   > >>> ct.windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA("kernel32")
   > 0
   > >>> ct.windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW("kernel32")
   > -1613692928
   > ```
2. Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011) for details on calling functions from *.dll*s via *CTypes* (in particular, you should set *restype* to a *64bit* value, *e.g.* *wintypes.HMODULE*)
3. There's no need for *GetModuleHandle* (making the previous 2 bullets moot for this particular case, but I left them because they contain useful general info). You could simply use **`load_addr = windll.LoadLibrary(sys.argv[1])._handle`**
4. Argument validation should come 1<sup>st</sup>

Comment: Note that `.restype` should be set or a 64-bit HMODULE could be truncated.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: thanks for the suggestion, that should have been covered by the answer referenced by the 2nd bullet. Anyway I added that piece of info in order to be explicit.